# Twitter API delete json messages

Tags: json, twitter, twitter-streaming-api

I'm using the Twitter streaming API and have come across these messages:

```
{"delete":{"status":{"id":1234,"id_str":"1234","user_id":3,"user_id_str":"3"}}}
```

Are there any other `delete` type messages other than `status`??

I'm finding it difficult to find any documentation on Twitter's dev sites.  I know there's the `scrub_geo` message, but it doesn't start with the `delete` at the beginning.  they look like:

```
{"scrub_geo":{
   "user_id":14090452,
   "user_id_str":"14090452",
   "up_to_status_id":23260136625,
   "up_to_status_id_str":"23260136625"
   }
}
```

I'm needing to know all the other delete type messages both that start with `delete` and those that don't.  I'm wanting to be compliant with the Twitter API terms. Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this helps. But...

Search for the word "destroy" in the api (https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1). Post requests can be sent to delete the following, so maybe the streaming API will push them back.

- Status
- Direct messages
- Friendships
- Blocks
- Favourites
- List members
- List subscribers
- Lists